# Cycles Render shows black screen

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm using Blender 2.92, and Cycles Render, and it rendered how it should, however after adding a fluid simulation, whenever I try to render an image, by pressing F12, it just produces a black screen, as seen below, however I can see my model rendered normaly as seen in the bottom picture, I have already tried changing the post-processing composition and sequencer options, I have also made sure to disable composition nodes and made sure that my nodes output what they should, and the camera is looking the way it should, I'm quite new so this is probably an easy fix that I missed; here are some things that may be important:

- I'm only able to use my CPU for rendering currently.
- My operating system is linux Arch.

[image]

[image]

Here is my blend file and everything it uses:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wnQ0gd-WJ30Zn52l_liXEngOIPrpIWry/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you disabled your whole collection for rendering. Enable it again and all will be fine.

[image]